# I would like to copy object shape and apply it to another object

Tags: objects

Let's say I have 2 bodies with different shape.

Body A is more fat while Body B is thinner.

I want to change body A to have a body B shape,

but keep the body A vertex group, weights and bones.

is this possible?

Comment: Check out this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34758/how-about-blendshapes-not-shape-keys May be helpful.

Comment: its not exactly what I wanted since 2 bodies has different vertices and edges. but thanks anyway this would be helpful.

Comment: Different vertices and edges? Do you mean 2 bodies has a different number of vertices?