# Blender: morphing object shape

Tags: animation, objects, shape-keys

I have two different objects in Blender. They have the same number of vertices and in the same order: Is there a way to morph one object into the other?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34758/is-it-possible-to-create-duplicates-of-a-mesh-that-can-be-deformed-and-used-as

Comment: I tried this out and worked pretty well. The only thing to remember is that the vertices need to be in the same order between objects if they are built through the mesh rather than two hard wired objects in blender. I needed to create an arrow that grows and turns in a direction. It was easier for me to build the initial arrow and then duplicate and edit. I t worked really well when I made sure to add all of the required vertices at the beginning. I had to build it a few times to get it right.

Answer (score 6):

Select both objects then in the mesh properties under ShapeKeys you will find an option to "Join as Shapes" in the menu under the add/remove buttons. This makes a shapekey in the active object that matches the other object.

With the shapekey selected in the list you can animate the value to morph between the two shapes. Either press <kbd>I</kbd> while the mouse is over the value or <kbd>[image: RMB]</kbd>right-click and select *Insert Keyframe*.

[image: Shapekey options]

[image: sample animation]